# Where do I go after saving Redd and Greyson?

Tags: the-sexy-brutale

Where do I go after saving Redd Rockridge and Greyson Grayson from being electrocuted in the theater?

I'm stuck on the north end of the ground floor:

[image: ground floor map]

There doesn't seem to be any way out. Well, there is, except for the fact that it is blocked off.

Where is the rest of the game?

Answer (score 2):

...you just got the power to pick any lock, like the one in the cage. The rest of the game is there.

[image]

Comment: Don’t forget to accept your answer.